# the purpose of using the setter and getter method?

Tags: php

I understand the code flow but I never use them because I don't know what is it for.. can you show me a practical way of using it?

the purpose of setter and getter method ?

```
<?php 
class person {
        var $name; 
        function set_name($new_name) { 
                $this->name = $new_name;  
        }

   function get_name() {
                return $this->name;
        }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Why tagged it to Java ? Nevertheless , you can have some validation in setters , you can keep the fields private and restrict access using accessors , your code becomes compatible with some of the existing frameworks which relies on bean style accessors !

Comment: i suggest you first upgrade to php 5 and then working with some structure that supports OO to some level.

Comment: Magic methods - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For trivial cases like this one, the getter and setters are frankly useless except for a strict interpretation of the Encapsulation Principle (which I endorse anyway).

They become useful when accessing a variable has side effects to be tracked or a variable that shouldn't be handled directly by the user but only through a strict, defined procedure: for example a global counter in a multithread environment.

Another useful aspect of a setter method is a validation of the data: let's say that the variable can hold only odd numbers greater than 100 and smaller than 200. Without a setter i can place any value I want, with the setter i can sanitize the input inside the object itself rather than outside.

All said, you should always use getters and setters. They might get handy in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Thue purpose of getter setter methods are mainly in Data Tranfer Objects(DTO) , beans etc where we want to transport objects with values from one layer to another

Comment: False, or at least incomplete. Encapsulation principle is much more important (and basic) than DTO

Comment: various layers like persistence layer , UI layer etc

Answer (score 1):

The purposes are different in both languages:

- in Java, setters and getters are part of the "Java Bean" standard, and serve to define public properties (properties are - by definition - things exposed as getters and setters); a lot of IDEs, wizards and libraries expect such methods (which, by the way, is a widely useful and equally misunderstood abstraction).
- in PHP they are less useful, but they do make it easier to control the type of an attribute (you can have type hints on methods and you can't have them on attributes)
- in PHP and Java they let you make certain things "write only"
- in PHP and Java they help people using IDEs in guessing "how to configure this object" - usually you can just type set, press ctrl+space and browse the configurable stuff.
- in both languages they add a bit of encapsulation and help in guarding your code against change (which is - arguably - less important in PHP, where you could use a magic __get method anyway).

Mostly, they are just question of style and uniformity.

Answer (score 0):

The `getter` and `setter` methods gives you centralized control on how a particular field is initialized, accessed and provided to client which makes validation and debugging much easier. You can simply put a breakpoints or print statement to see which threads are accessing and what values are going out.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is you can use getters and setters to control values as they come in:

```
<?php 
class car{
    var $engineSize;

    function setEngineSize($size) { 
        if($size > 0){
            $this->engineSize = $size;
    }
} 
?>
```